# Azure notification hub sending notifications to iOS only

Tags: android, ios, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I'm working on a multi-platform app which includes push notifications. The issue I'm facing is described in the images below

1st Scenario :

[image]

2nd Scenario :

[image]

However, when I test notification hub (using azure portal or Visual Studio), I receive notifications on all the devices.
It seems that Azure Notification Hub is ignoring Android devices when an iOS device uses the same account (tag).

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please attach the example of the notification you are trying to send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that type of issues, use the [Service Bus Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530751.aspx). Likely, your Android app did not subscribe successfully for some reason. Subscribing different apps working on the different platforms to the same tag should not be a problem - i saw it working many times, and implemented that by myself.

If you see in the Service Bus Explorer (see registrations for your NH, and search for your android app registration and the tags field) that your android app is subscribed to the tag, but you see no notifications, check if your notification is malformed.