# Azure Notification Hub on Android. How to send to specific user?

Tags: c#, android, wpf, azure, azure-notificationhub

I want to create a little application to send notification to my Android Device.

I made a WPF Application and an Android Application and I use Azure Notification Hub and GCM for notif.

I can send a notification for all my android device but not for ONE device.

And i come here to get your help to do this.

My WPF Application work like this :

```
 private async void SendNotificationAsync()
    { 
        var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(Keys.FullConnectionString, Keys.NotificationHubName);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtTo.Text)) 
            await hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(
                    "{'to': '" + TxtTo.Text + "', 'data': { 'message': '" + TxtMessage.Text + "', 'title': '" + TxtTitle.Text + "' } }");
        else
        {
            await hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(
                    "{'data': { 'message': '" + TxtMessage.Text + "', 'title': '" + TxtTitle.Text + "' } }");
        }
    }
```

My problem is this:

I don't understand how to get the Android ID Device Registration, or then, it's my RegistrationId generated with my OnRegistered method :

```
 protected override void OnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
    {
        Log.Verbose(MyBroadcastReceiver.TAG, "GCM Registered: " + registrationId);

        RegistrationId = registrationId;
        ChangeTextID(registrationId);

        Hub = new NotificationHub(Keys.NotificationHubName, Keys.ListenConnectionString, context);

        try
        {
            Hub.UnregisterAll(registrationId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(MyBroadcastReceiver.TAG, ex.Message);
        }

        var tags = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            Hub.Register(registrationId, tags.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(MyBroadcastReceiver.TAG, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

But if i use this ID to send my notification (in my WPF app) it dosen't work (Replace TxtTo.Text)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use anything for sending targeted push notification except tag you subscribed that application to.
When you register the application for the notification hub, it will put its record into the notification hub backend registrations table (which you may access to from Azure Portal or using [Service Bus Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530751.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). If you subscribed your application to a tag, and send the notification to that tag, and application did not receive it, then see if you have that application in the table with the appropriate tag.

That is the great feature because you may send targeted notifications to users without knowing their IDs or whatever. [Just subscribe them](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-send-breaking-news/) to that tag. That works perfectly among platforms - we use that approach to send targeted notifications for users subscribed to the same tag on different devices and platforms.

[May be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983234/azure-notification-hub-sending-notifications-to-ios-only/36989667#36989667) relevant. As i see, you send your notification not to a tag (try to add to SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync extra argument like [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-notify-users/#sending-notifications-from-the-webapi-backend)). Try to send it to the exact tag (you can do that from a portal, Notification Hub dashboard => DEBUG pane).